Getting ECONNRESET Error When Publishing Data to MQTT Broker Using paho-mqtt in Python
I'm doing a project for class, and I need to send data values from a device to other. I thought that the best option was to use MQTT.
I'm using the broker test.mosquitto.org. I need to send persistently messages, and I'm having an error called econnreset, and I don't know if is bad of my code or from the server that don't lets to send too many messages. If anyone could help me.
That's my code:
import network
import time
import dataCollectOnly as data
import machine
from umqtt.simple import MQTTClient

conversion_factor = 3.3 / (65535) 
sensor_temp = machine.ADC(machine.ADC.CORE_TEMP)

wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
wlan.active(True)
wlan.connect('Jordi', '65352170T')

max_wait = 10
while max_wait > 0:
    if wlan.status() < 0 or wlan.status() >= 3:
        break
    max_wait -= 1
    print('waiting for connection...')
    time.sleep(1)

if wlan.status() != 3:
    raise RuntimeError('network connection failed')
else:
    print('connected')
    status = wlan.ifconfig()
    print( 'ip = ' + status[0] )
        
mqtt_server = 'test.mosquitto.org'
client_id = 'idc'
topic_pub = 'project/room/stats/temp'

def mqtt_connect():
    client = MQTTClient(client_id, mqtt_server, keepalive=3600)
    client.connect()
    print('Connected to %s MQTT Broker'%(mqtt_server))
    return client

def reconnect():
   print('Failed to connect to the MQTT Broker. Reconnecting...')
   time.sleep(5)
   machine.reset()
   
   
try:
    client = mqtt_connect()
except OSError as e:
    reconnect()
while True:
    client.publish(topic_pub, data.stats())
    time.sleep(5)



Are using the same MQTT client id across multiple devices/clients?

No, I only have a publisher and one subscriber

And they both have different client ids? (since you've only shown the code for one of them) Also given this is a public test broker, you really should be using longer + random client ids as you have no idea what others may be using
